# pull characters from string based on fixed character

Tags: sql

In an SQL query, I know how to use Left, Right and Mid but is there a way to pull values from a column leading up to a specific character in the column?  Such as a column that looks like this:

testemail@test.com|Something Else|Error

I want everything from the left up to the first | but since this is an email address, there isn't a fixed value of characters in the address.  I think this is easy but I just can't remember the function for this if there is one.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `charindex()` in combination with `substring()`.

Comment: Thanks.  That was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this with substring and charindex:

```
Select     substring([field],1,charindex('|',[field1]) -1 ) from table1
```

Replace field1 with your field.

CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )

Searches an expression for another expression and returns its starting position if found.